# Azure B2C authentication without a ClientSecret

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've successfully implemented [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) and have a client + server working locally.

However, the front-end application that I'm building is an Angular app - this means that it isn't possible to store a client secret in it..

Relevant code:

```cs
ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.ClientId, Startup.Authority, Startup.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(Startup.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

var user = cca.Users.FirstOrDefault();

AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, user, Startup.Authority, false);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

How can I set my frontend up securely to work without having a client secret, based on the tutorial mentioned?

I'm currently using this [angular library](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using *implicit grant flow*

You can seamlessly integrate into any SPA application.

Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa, this article helps you.

There is an SPA sample already available in GitHub, you can try https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-hellojs-singlepageapp

you can use oidc-client library instead hello.js in above sample, both are very similar and easy to implement.